# R: RCurl postForm() with Content-Length > 1024

Tags: r, curl, libcurl, rcurl, http-content-length

I'm having trouble POSTing data with Content-Length > 1024 using RCurl and postForm(). How can I increase the size limit of my HTTP request?

```
curl.opts <- list(httpheader = "Expect:",
                  httpheader = "Accept:text/xml",
                  verbose = TRUE,
                  followlocation = TRUE)

hmm <- postForm(myurl, longtxt=lotsoftext, 
               style = "POST", .opts = curl.opts)
```

Whenever Content-Length is < 1024 the server responds as it should, while > 1024 results in an error. Using "curl" from the command line on the other hand works fine also for long content.

Comment: Whoops. Don't know how I missed that. The other suggestion there seemed to be to request http 1.0 (using option `http.version`) instead of the default.

Comment: with http.version = "1.0" ?

Comment: neh.. no difference I'm afraid

Comment: it'll help if you clarify what "results in an error" means with more details

Comment: I doubt you'll get a useful answer unless you can provide a reproducible example